# How to combine array and hash by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array and a hash. The array contains dates and the hash contains a date as key and a float as value (revenue_green).

This is my array:

```
@reporting_dates = @month_ends.find_all {|e| e < @current_reporting_date.to_s } <<
  @current_reporting_date
```

And my hash:

```
@revenue_green = @reports_at_reporting_dates.sum('revenue_green')
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
@reporting_dates: ["2017-01-27", "2017-02-24", Fri, 10 Mar 2017]
@revenue_green: {Fri, 10 Mar 2017=>7.0}
```

For two dates of `@reporting_dates` (2017-01-27 and 2017-02-24) `@revenue_green` does not have any values.

I want to create a hash that gives me the following output:

```
@new_hash: {2017-01-27 => 0, 2017-02-24 => 0, 2017-03-10 => 7.0}
```

so for all dates where no `revenue_green` exists it should put a 0.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

```
@month_ends = ["2017-01-27", "2017-02-24", "2017-03-31", "2017-04-28",
               "2017-05-26", "2017-06-30", "2017-07-28", "2017-08-25",
               "2017-09-29", "2017-10-27", "2017-11-24", "2017-12-29"]

@all_dates = (Date.new(@reporting_year).
  beginning_of_year..1.month.from_now).
  to_a.reverse.select { |day| day.wday == 5 }

@current_reporting_date = @all_dates.select { |d| d <= Date.today }.first

@all_reports = Report.all

@reports_at_reporting_dates = @all_reports.where(:day => @reporting_dates).order(:day)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and insert your code sample as text instead of as an image?

Comment: ok  i updated my question with code.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum code that will duplicate the problem. `@month_ends`, `@current_reporting_date` and `@reports_at_reporting_dates` are not defined so we can't run and test to help you.

Comment: ok i added all missing variables. i know my code is not pretty but it works for now (i will refactor at a later stage in my project)

Comment: I reformatted your code so that readers wouldn't have to scroll horizontally to read it. I trust you don't mind. Your questions concerns the manipulation of the values of `@reporting_dates` and `@revenue_green`. How you obtained those values is not relevant. "This is my array" to (but not including ) "I want to create a hash..." should be removed. I don't understand why you added the "edit" section, as it does not reference the two instance variables referenced above or `@new_hash`. I don't see that any (much less all) variables need to be instance variables (rather than local variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your starting objects are

```
@reporting_dates = ["2017-01-27", "2017-02-24", "Fri, 10 Mar 2017"]
@revenue_green = {"Fri, 10 Mar 2017"=>7.0}
```

(i.e., quotes around "Fri, 10 Mar 2017"), then this should work:

```
require 'date'
@new_hash = Hash.new
@reporting_dates.each {|d| @new_hash[Date.parse(d)] = @revenue_green[d] || 0}

@new_hash => {#<Date: 2017-01-27 ((2457781j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>0, #<Date: 2017-02-24 ((2457809j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>0, #<Date: 2017-03-10 ((2457823j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>7.0}
```

or, if you want the keys in the new hash to be strings,

```
@reporting_dates.each {|d| @new_hash[Date.parse(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = @revenue_green[d] || 0}

@new_hash => {"2017-01-27"=>0, "2017-02-24"=>0, "2017-03-10"=>7.0}
```

Comment: ok with this solution i get a new hash, however all values are 0

Comment: I ran all the code that I posted, in ruby 2.2.3, and got the @new_hash I posted, both versions.

Comment: Just changed "@reporting_dates: ..." to "@reporting_dates = ..." to make code easier to copy and paste.

Comment: I made it work!! I had to change @revenue_green[d] to @revenue_green[d.to_date]. If you update your solution I click to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Oliver, you're evidently using rails, because to_date isn't a String method in pure Ruby.  But I can't in good conscience change my answer, because it works fine as is (i.e., without the ".to_date") with the original parameters you  supplied, in both irb and rails console (arguably better in rails console, because you don't need "require 'date'"). https://repl.it/GX3u/0  Follow your heart.